# Responsive image resize and selectively crop it's width with a set of rules

Tags: html, css, responsive, crop, image-resizing

I want a background image to appear at the top part and fully cover the width of a page. As you can see, the image is quite wide and short - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjYqj.jpg. This should be the header image of a page, with the contents of the page appearing below it.

If the browser's width is bigger than the image's original width, the image's width and height should be enlarged proportionally (together with its container - thus pushing downwards the page's contents that appear under the image).

If the browser's width is smaller than the image's original width, the image should retain its original size without shrinking, and be cropped from both sides **until a 15% crop is reached from each side** (You can see that the image has quite wide green areas on both sides which are safe for cropping).

The tricky part is that once 15% of the crop has been reached from each side, I want the image to start shrinking proportionally to the browser's width, thus the middle 70% of the image will always be seen, and the image will never be cropped more than 15% from each side.

The height of the image (and it's container) should rescale automatically in proportion with the image's width. If the image's height (together with its container) shrinks to be smaller than it's original size, the page's contents are pushed up so the distance between the page's contents and the image is always kept the same.

I'm looking for a clean solution (preferably with CSS only) similar to this:
https://demodern.de/projekte/mediengruppe-rtl

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of using CSS it is pretty simple to make everything work as you need. In order to do this you might use the image as it is via  and the same image on a parent element's background. But you will have to adjust your CSS to work with this image ONLY. In case if you will try to use another image - you will have to adjust paddings or mediaqueries. Solution that works a kind of ONE time for a specific image, but still, it doesn't use JS at all, which is great. And regarding referencing the image twice - it is not a problem for a browser. It will make only one http request for a single unique media asset so no performance problems from this perspective.
Here is a way how you might do what you want:

```
.wrapper {
  background: url(/images/_m1NuVvd.jpeg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 38%;
}
.wrapper img {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  display:none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1338px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .wrapper img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="/images/_m1NuVvd.jpeg" />
</div>
```

Make sure to use a proper path to your image instead of /images/_m1NuVvd.jpeg.
BTW, in future it will be better to probide links to the images in a way, so those might be reused in jsfiddle. Dropbox doesn't allow to use the image via that link.
Best wishes

Comment: Thank you Dimas. The thing is I need the code to dynamically process any image size without knowing it's dimensions in advance, and crop it to a maximum of 15% from each side. That's why your code does not address this issue. (BTW - I edited the image's link location, so it's no longer pointing to Dropbox)

Comment: It's ok but... CSS + simple + solution? LoL!